# Mysql Select query not fetching data with WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting an error in a MySQL query.

> **MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0000 sec)**

My SQl Query is

```
"SELECT * FROM `transactions` WHERE pan_no = 'ADMPN2123Z'"
```

Data row already exists in table.

`pan_no` structure is `varchar 255` No None

Comment: What is the data in table? It is not an error.

Comment: id = 677, name = khemchand lakhera, pan_no = ADMPN2123Z

Comment: when i execute "SELECT * FROM  `transactions`" it's working but not in WHERE clause case

Comment: How about this: `"SELECT * FROM `transactions` WHERE id=677"`

Comment: try `SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE pan_no LIKE 'ADM%'`. It might be that just 1 character is slightly off? Have you tried copying and pasting that `pan_no` too?

Comment: there must be some space in your database.plaese check

Comment: check pan_no data has any space,if so trim the values before you store it

Comment: WHERE TRIM(pan_no) = 'ADMPN2123Z'

Comment: With WHERE id=677" clause it's working but when i am trying WHERE pan_no LIKE 'ADM%' it's not working.

Comment: Thanks for support guys. Finally i got it i am getting space in field value. Now how can i resolve this.

Comment: But you need to show where you were getting space.. @KhemChandLakhera

Comment: i am getting space field value in data row.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems right. Please check spaces, variables and database. If you use it in php code try directly in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue, I inserting data in utf encoded format. Issue resolved by placing mysql_real_escape_string() to data.